# I have created FIRE!

Tags: foley

Hey guys,

I want to share another discovery in my studio.

I recently bought a used camera lens of e-bay to use with my digital camera.

It was sent to me in a small cardboard box with a ton of bubble wrapping inside of it.

I took the lens out to examine it, and stuffed the bubble wrap back inside the box.

I turned my back to the box and examined the lens.

I suddenly heard the sound of a crackling fire behind me. You know, one of those sappy log camp fires with loud snaps and pops. It's caused by the natural unfolding of the paper after it's been stuffed in a box - it sounds surprisingly realistic.

I instantly ran inside the record room and recorded it.

I'll post up a sample tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

[youtube]Vrd13cGv2GU[/youtube]

Comment: This film is rad!

Comment: I own it... and make friends sit down and watch it.

Comment: Haha! You make "friends" sit down and watch it, and when they stand up again they are just acquaintances? 

Answer (score 2):

That's not too surprising. Plastic wrap (celophane) was a fairly standard foley prop for creating fire sounds for a while. It's always fun finding those things by accident though. ;)

Comment: Bleh I thought I was onto something here! It's part of my series of discovery of external sounds inside the studio ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to steal the limelight here @Utopia, but I -- quite intentionally though -- created fire last summer with bubble wrap, the microfiber cloth that came with my Mac and the very thin paper that sometimes come inside new shoes filling them up.

I used the bubble wrap for bursts while the thin paper gave a nice, quite intense, crackling. The microfiber cloth gave me the best "flame flap" since it is soft and dense. I'll post a sample too!

Answer (score 1):

Looking forward to hearing it Utopia. I use a potato chip packet or the wrapping from a vacuum sealed coffee packet like Nabob. But the bubble wrap also sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

post samples! great stuff! if you haven't seen it:
http://soundworkscollection.com/imagineering

at 5 minutes he shows how they created fire :D

Answer (score 0):

I made fire out of a flanger and toothpicks!

Comment: @Chris So, how did you do that? :)